# How to Set Custom Keyboard Shortcut to Adjust Volumes and Brightness

Tags: macbook-pro, shortcut, preferences

Is there a way to setup custom keyboard shortcut to adjust volumes and brightness? I'm using a MacBook Pro with Touchbar and it's really hard to use.

Comment: What's wrong with the standard volume (F11/F12) and brightness (F1/F2) keys?

Comment: i m using a mac with touchbar. its really hard to use.

Comment: With the Touch Bar you can instantly emulate up/down buttons for brightness and volume by **flicking left or right** on the button. Instead of opening the slider and sliding, a quick flick will increment or decrement by one step just like regular keys used to.